# Help in debugging the string concatenation code

Tags: java, debugging, concatenation

I have a code to concatenate strings. However, for some reason, the final string is not a combination of the required strings. Consider the following code :

```
//cusEmail is of type String[]
String toList = "";
for(i=0; i < cusEmail.length - 1; i++) {
    toList.concat(cusEmail[i]);
    toList.concat("; ");
    System.out.println(cusEmail[i]);
}
toList.concat(cusEmail[i]);
System.out.println(toList);
```

The first sout statement displays the strings in cusEmail[i] correctly. However, once concatenated, the second sout displays a blank / empty. Any reason for this? Am i concatenating it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String` objects are immutable.  Calling `concat` on `toList` will not change the value of the `toList` object.  Instead `concat` will return a different `String` object that is a concatenation of the two strings.  For your example, you will want to store the result of each of the calls to `concat` in the `toList` variable.

For example,

```
toList = toList.concat(cusEmail[i]);
```

An alternative to using the `concat` method would be to use the concatenation operator.  This might be a little nicer to read.

```
toList = toList + cusEmail[i];
```

Note, however, that each time one string is concatenated onto another string, a new `String` object needs to be created that contains copies of the information in the two original strings.  This can be a costly way of building a string when it is done over and over in a loop such as what you have.  This is true whether you use the `concat` method or the concatenation operator.  An alternative is to use a `StringBuilder` object to build your string.

```
StringBuilder toList = new StringBuilder();
for(i=0; i < cusEmail.length - 1; i++) {
    toList.append(cusEmail[i]);
    toList.append("; ");
    System.out.println(cusEmail[i]);
}
toList.append(cusEmail[i]);
System.out.println(toList.toString());
```

Answer (score 3):

String is *immutable* . This means that `toList.concat(..)` doesn't change `toList`. Instead it returns a new String:

```
 toList = toList.concat(..);
```

However, it is more advisable to use `StringBuilder.append(..)`:

```
StringBuilder toList = new StringBuilder();
for (...) {
    sb.append(emails[i]);
    sb.append("; ");
}
...
return sb.toString();
```

An even better (in terms of code reuse) way is to use an utility for contatenating strings with delimiters. Like [`ArrayUtils.join(emailsArray, "; ")`;](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) (from commons-lang)